# createReadStream end fires before data finished processing

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, stream, fs

I am trying to do the following:

1. Stream a csv file in line by line.
2. Modify the data contained in each line.
3. Once all lines are streamed and processed, finish and move on to next task.

The problem is `.on("end")` fires before `.on("data")` finishes processing each line. How can I get `.on("end")` to fire after `.on("data")` has finished processing all the lines?

Below is a simple example of what I am talking about:

```
import parse from 'csv-parse'; 

var parser = parse({});

fs.createReadStream(this.upload.location)
.pipe(parser)
.on("data", line => {
  var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  num = num % 3;
  num = num * 1000;
  setTimeout( () => { 
    console.log('data process complete');
  }, num);
})
.on("end", () => {
   console.log('Done: parseFile');
   next(null);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end): "Note that the 'end' event will not fire unless the data is completely consumed. " I can only imagine something bizarre is happening.

Comment: Could it be that `pipe` and `data` are not meant to be used together? Maybe add a `data` event handler to whatever `parser` is rather than here?

Comment: That is a smart idea. Parser is referencing `import parse from 'csv-parse';` I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the `setTimeout` (or any other async task) within the `data` event listener. `end` is firing after `data` but the async task is causing it to log messages even after the stream fires `end`.

If you take out the `setTimeout` then you'll see that it logs all the messages in data before `end`. You can still perform async tasks but there will be a potential batch of them that  run after the stream has ended.

This code helps explain what is going on:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const testFileName = 'testfile.txt'

fs.writeFileSync(testFileName, '123456789')

let count = 0
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(testFileName, {
  encoding: 'utf8',
  highWaterMark: 1  // low highWaterMark so we can have more chunks to observe
})
readStream.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('+++++++++++processing sync+++++++++++++')
  console.log(data)
  console.log('+++++++++++end processing sync+++++++++++++')
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('-----------processing async-------------')
    console.log(data)
    console.log('-----------end processing async-------------')
  }, ++count * 1000)
})
readStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('stream ended but still have async tasks doing their thing')
  fs.unlinkSync(testFileName)
})
```